# Where can I get Perl 4?

Tags: perl

I have a need to test some Perl 4 code.  It will run on an ancient (pre-386) machine that I don't currently have access to.  I would like to compile it for OS X, but I can't find the source on CPAN (it seems to only go back to 5.004).

Comment: The Perl Git repo at http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git includes history going back to release 1.0.

Comment: I can't stop wondering - why do people post answers as comments?

Comment: http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/shortlog?pg=635 lists 4.x versions.

Comment: [Perl 1 to Perl 4.0 (patch 36)](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/tags?after=perl-5a9)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original simtel archive is down, but this link will give you a version of Perl 4.19 that will run on an 8086:

http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/simtelnet/msdos/perl/

The filename is perl419x.zip and has been tested on on DOS 4.3 with 640k of memory and works.

Answer (score 11):

http://www.cpan.org/src/unsupported/4.036/

Which I got to from http://perl.org => DOWNLOAD => Perl source code => unsupported

Comment: Thanks that looks promising

Comment: If you get it to compile tell us what you did. The last time I tried to get it running using the modern tools I couldn't get it to happen.

Comment: @briandfoy I wound up using a precompiled perl from the link Sean Hayden gave running in DosBox as it is sorta close to the final environment. I did look into compiling from source for OS X, but I don't think it is possible. I think Perl 4 required static linking and OS X doesn't have static libs. Might try again in Linux, but I have different fish to fry.